# Getting Type mismatch error after convert Java class to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm in the midst of converting an existing app from Java to Kotlin. I'm now stuck at this error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Any! but Nothing was expected
```

Been searching on this since morning and still couldn't figured it out. Following are the code snippet on my issue.

```
val gson = Gson()
val response = gson.fromJson<Any>(responseText, classOfT) // classOfT: Class<*> // sample value = AnyModelClassess::class.java
responseHandler.onResponse(response)
```

The onResponse

```
interface ResponseHandler<T> {
   fun onResponse(response: T)
   fun onErrorResponse(code: Int, msg: String?)
}
```

Can anyone help explain and solve this issue? I'm still quite new to Kotlin and don't really know.

Comment: @SantanuSur Tried that and got "Projections are not allowed on type arguments of functions and properties"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to overcome this issue.
I change my interface to this:

```
interface ResponseHandler {
   fun onResponse(response: Any?)
   fun onErrorResponse(code: Int, msg: String?)
}
```

Then the `onResponse` will expect `Any?` and I could compile and proceed with my Kotlin migration. I'm not sure this is a proper workaround or not, but this is what I did to overcome this issue. My initial testing seems this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove the type specified in gson.fromJson. Like below

```
val response = gson.fromJson(responseText, classOfT)
```

Hence your final code will be

```
val gson = Gson()
val response = gson.fromJson(responseText, classOfT) 
responseHandler.onResponse(response)
```

Comment: Still getting that error "Type mismatch. Required: Nothing Found: Any!"

Comment: what is classOfT? is it something like this ? customModel::class.java.

Comment: Yes correct, I put it as comment on the second line. To make it compile able, now I put "response is Nothing" check, but I don't know if it will break in certain situation

Comment: You mean classOfT change from Class<*> to Class<String>, is it? Tried and still cannot. "Type mismatch: inferred type is String! but Nothing was expected"

Comment: If the responseText is null then it would give run time exception and crash.

Comment: What is the responseText? is it a string of Json ? can you paste the responseText here?

Comment: Yes, a String of JSON. It is the API response and here I want to convert it into class object based on classOfT.
Sample JSON, {"status": 1,"message": success,"data": {"user": {"username": "abc","name": "ABC","email": "test@abc.com"}}}